# C# Using data in a .sqlite file (not a .db)

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

So i'm kind of new to SQL and such however I have been using c# for a while. This is my first question on StackOverflow so if I did something wrong let me know.

The file I want to use is not a .db file which is what most of the info I've read is about. It's a .sqlite file and I was wondering how I would be able to use the data in it for a program I'm writing. I would prefer to not use a third party resource but I will if I have to. The file also changes every few days so I don't want to simply convert it externally to .csv or something.

Like I said I don't know much about SQL so any help is appreciated. If someone could show me how to make this data usable I would be very thankful.

EDIT: Ok so i'm using Visual Studio 2015 to write the code and the file does not contain any commands just stats sort of like an excel file. It has 14 different tables each having info on different things. I'm going to try the method recommended by @inquisitive_mind and I'll let you all know if it worked. Thanks for the help so far! :)

Comment: use this library to open the sqlite database with c#: https://system.data.sqlite.org/ all the information you need is there. Also it doesn't matter which extension the file has. If its is called .db or .sqlite or .anything really does not matter as long as it is a sqlite database

Comment: can you explain which .net app you are using asp,wpf or windows-store

Comment: The name of the file is of no concern; what kind of data does it actually contain? SQL commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code to read data from SQL Lite databases.You need to download the following dll System.Data.SQLite.dll and reference that in your project.The dll can be found here [SQL Lite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

For example:I have a table called Scalars with 3 columns in the .sqlite file located in the variable sFilePath.So the code to get the data would look something like this

```
using System.Data.SQLite;

using (SQLiteConnection oSqlLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + sFilePath))
{
     oSqlLiteConnection.Open();
     SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("Select * from Scalars", oSqlLiteConnection);
     SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     while (dr.Read())
         Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", dr.GetValue(0), dr.GetValue(1), dr.GetValue(2)));
}
```

Comment: Ok so I installed the .dll and ran the code you had changing scalars to a table and sFilePath to the file path and it gives me: 

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: Nvm i figured it out I removed \t{3}

Thank you so much!